# How to add image in tableview first cell,rest of them are strings

Tags: uitableview, swift3

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
var names = ["jan","feb","mar"]
let image = UIImage.init(named: "dine001")
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

how to add image in firstCell,remaining cells are strings

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForRowAt:indexPath:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

if indexPath.row == 0 {
   cell.imageView.image = self.image
} else {
   cell.textLabel.text = names[indexPath.row]
}
```